# CollectionView cell unexpected behaviour swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My cells get created based on `timeSlotArray` with holds all the opening time time slots in 30 minutes increments, but gets its color based on if it's Id is equal to any of the `bookedTimeSlotsArray` entries IDs.
If I select a day that have bookings, it gets the cells the right colour, but cells will keep that color on reloading data, even if I change to a date with other bookings.

The function is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeSlotCell", for: indexPath) as! TimeSlotCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeSlotArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellId = Int("\(String(describing: self.selectedDate))" + self.timeStringToStringConvert(timeSlotArray[indexPath.row]))

    if bookedTimeSlotsArray.count > 0 {
        for index in 0...bookedTimeSlotsArray.count - 1 {
            let bookingId = bookedTimeSlotsArray[index].bookingId

            if cell.cellId == bookingId {
                print("   match found")
                print("Index is: \(index)")
                print("cell time is: \(timeSlotArray[indexPath.row])")
                print("time slot cell id is: \(String(describing: cell.cellId))")
                print("booking id: \(bookingId)")
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

I reload  collection view data in 2 functions, `calculateOpenTimeSlots()`and`calculateBookedTimeSlots()`and they get called like this:
1st case: in `viewDidLoad()`I call both functions,
2nd case: in `Firebase`observer function I call only `calculateBookedTimeSlots()`, 3rd case: in changing day from selecting table view cell I call only `calculateOpenTimeSlots()`in `didSelectRowAt`.
1st and 3rd cases are working as expected, but 2nd is not as described at the beginning of the question. Can you guys se where I'm hitting the wall??
Many thanks as usual.

EDIT:

I added a `prepareForReuse` to my cell`s class but I still get the same behaviour when collection view draws the cells.
Here's the cell class:

```
import UIKit

class TimeSlotCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    var cellId: Int!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // Set your default background color, title color etc
        backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the first question but for the second one, you need to reset backgroundColor in else block. You should not forget that Cells are being reused.

Comment: @RikeshSubedi. Thanks for point it out. That was it for the cell color, and actually I had thought that solution, but as a workaround, not the correct way to do things, still gotta learn much I see.
As for the firs question, as you can see from the prints I get two sets of prints per loop, can you see why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54414667/4144315 you can refer this.

Comment: Great thanks. I thought that by setting the background color in properties inspector I wouldn't need to specify it in code as it would change it only if the if statement was satisfied every time it would redraw the cells..lesson learned.

Comment: Nope, still not working. now I have 2 booking of one hour each in 2 different days, that means 4 time slots to compare and it goes correctly, but it's skipping the first match..it only gets the second one..

Comment: @RikeshSubedi. I added `override open func prepareForReuse() {
                    super.prepareForReuse()
            // Set your default background color, title color etc
            backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        }`in cell class but still is not showing the first match.
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @karthik. Following your link I did change my custom cell class, but still I have the same behaviour. I edited my question to be clearer. Can you see why `prepareForReuse`is not working?

Comment: @karthik. I just thought of doing that to help you understand where the problem was, and I had this idea and it was the right one, see my solution.
Thanks for trying helping me, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I cancelled the `else`statement after `if` statement in  `cellForItemAt`as now `prepareForReuse`is setting the default cell.
It all now works as expected.
The final function is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeSlotCell", for: indexPath) as! TimeSlotCollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeSlotArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.cellId = Int("\(String(describing: self.selectedDate))" + self.timeStringToStringConvert(timeSlotArray[indexPath.row]))

        if bookedTimeSlotsArray.count > 0 {
            for index in 0...bookedTimeSlotsArray.count - 1 {
                let bookingId = bookedTimeSlotsArray[index].bookingId

                if cell.cellId == bookingId {
                    print("   match found")
                    print("Index is: \(index)")
                    print("cell time is: \(timeSlotArray[indexPath.row])")
                    print("time slot cell id is: \(String(describing: cell.cellId))")
                    print("booking id: \(bookingId)")
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: yes that is the solution that I tried to implement, dough at first I thought I should do both things in the accepted solution, after a while re reading it I thought that it was suggesting the `prepareForReuse`method as an alternative to the firs part and so by using that I shouldn't use the `else`statement in 'cellForItemAt`function.
Again, many thanks.